# (SCSS) Changing properties of preceding element based on the state of succeeding element

Tags: html, css, sass

I have the following setup in HTML and SCSS -

```
h1 {
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  + p {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
p {
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}
<h1>Main title</h1>
<p>Sub-title goes there here</p>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is, I want `<h1>`'s `margin-bottom` to change from `24p`x to `0px` when there's `<p>` tag after it, but if there's no `<p>` tag, then the `margin-bottom` in `<h1>` will remain `24px`.

I tried using `&` operator but I can't seem to get my head around it.

```
h1 {
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  & + {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
  + p {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
p {
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}
```

What do you think I should do? Do I need to use `@if` directive for this certain case?

Comment: You cannot style the `h1` element depending on whether it has a succeeding `p` element or not. There is no such selector in CSS and so it wouldn't be possible with Sass/SCSS also because they ultimately get compiled into CSS.

Comment: If I understand what you are after correctly you can't do this, you can only traverse down, not up. This means you could effect the `margin` of a `p` that is preceded by a `h1` but not the `margin` of a `h1` that is succeeded by a `p`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### This is not possible due to the way CSS works

What you are looking to achieve is ultimately not possible. SASS compiles into CSS which is only traversed it one direction. This means you can target elements which are preceded by another element but you cannot select elements that are succeeded by another element.

### What can you do?

Given this restriction the most suitable way of achieving your result would be to change the logic so that the `margin-bottom` on the `h1` is replaced with `margin-top` on the `p` tag.

#### SASS

```
h1 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  + p {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
}
p {
  margin-top: 24px;
}
```

#### Compiled example

```css
h1 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
h1 + p {
  margin-top: 0;
}
p {
  margin-top: 24px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Main title</h1>
<p>Sub-title goes there here</p>
```

If you can't move the `margin` from the `h1` to the `p` tag it would be acceptable to use a negative `margin-top` on the `p` to offset the `margin-bottom` on the `h1`.

#### SASS

```
h1 {
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  + p {
    margin-top: -24px;
  }
}
p {
  margin-top: 24px;
}
```

#### Compiled example

```css
h1 {
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}
h1 + p {
  margin-top: -24px;
}
p {
  margin-top: 24px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Main title</h1>
<p>Sub-title goes there here</p>
```